# "If you don't need to access the actual object instance, you can wrap it in a `reactive`"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

According to the [doc](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-fundamentals.html#ref-unwrapping):

> If you don't need to access the actual object instance, you can wrap it in a `reactive`:
>
> ```js
> nested: reactive({
>   count,
> })
> ```

Can't understand this tip, can anyone provide a real world example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that tip appears to make little sense.

Based on the changes in the [commit](https://github.com/vuejs/docs-next/commit/3e5e52e9fdd3abbaab19849dc0dd81752d216216) that introduced the tip, I think it meant to say:

> If you don't want to unwrap the value in the template, you can wrap the value in a `reactive` within `setup()`.

That is, the following code:

```js
export default {
  setup() {
    const count = ref(0)
    return {
      nested: {
        count
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...requires explicit unwrapping in the template:

```html
<template>               
  <div>{{ nested.count.value }}</div>
</template>
```

But using `reactive()` around the nested object here:

```js
export default {
  setup() {
    const count = ref(0)
    return {      
      nested: reactive({
        count
      })
    }
  }
}
```

...allows the template to be less verbose:

```html
<template>
  <div>{{ nested.count }}</div>
</template>
```